# Как остановить программу в python без модуля time имея возможность восстановить работу программы?

Tags: python, распознавание-речи

Я создаю голосового помощника в питоне и нужно, чтобы при определённых действиях он останавливался на какое то время, но не с модулем time, и ещё мне нужно, чтобы при определённых действиях программа могла продолжить работу.

Comment: Сделайте `time.sleep` на 1 секунду и в цикле вызывайте до тех пор, пока не нужно остановиться

Comment: может вам стоит взять гуи и нарисовать 2 кнопки- старт и стоп? надо включил, не надо выключил.

Comment: Хорошая идея, возьму на заметку, но пока, мне намного более интересно конкретно голосовое управление

Answer (score 0):

Не использовать модуль time не выход! Как я понял, вам нужно лишь приостановить выполнение скрипта?

```
while True: continue
```

Лично у меня, потребляемое ЦП дошло до 60%. НЕ круто, чел.

А на счет этого:

```
while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Диспетчер задач вовсе не видел потребление ЦП 0(!)%.
Так воот. Это вам мысль к размышлению. Вам стоит поискать оптимальный баланс отклик/цена.

Ближе к вашей задаче: почему вы отказываетесь от бесконечного цикла с проверкой на «определенные действия», при которых программа продолжит работу? По мне так проще - лучше.

```
import time


def asleep():

    """ Я, к сожалению, не имею никаких «определенных действий»,
        поэтому.. СПИ ВЕЧНО, МО-ыта.2
    """
    return True

while asleep():

    time.sleep(.1)
```

Я действительно не понимаю вашей категоричности по поводу использования модуля time, ведь это по моему единственный выход реализовать это более менее на чистом python'е. Может вы экстремист и хотите удариться в написание дополнительной мини-утилиты под вашу задачу, в которой вы так же будете использовать библиотеку времени? Ну, это, конечно, выход для некоторых. Повторюсь: проще - лучше.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я это делаю для удобства и поэтому, хочу, чтобы можно было через if с возможностью при условии возобновить работу программу ещё до окончания time.sleep(), что этот метод не позволяет, к сожалению

Comment: Ладно. Вас не устраивает проверка условия каждые 10 милисекунд? По моему это достойный отклик.

Comment: Я не совсем понял про что вы говорите

Comment: хм. while не_выполнены_определенные_действия: подожди_10_милисекунд_и_повтори_цикл_если_определенные_действия_еще_не_выполнены. Я даже не знаю... Вы вникали в мой ответ? То есть тут сложно описать очевидное. Ладно... Условие вечно проверяется каждые 10 милисекунд, что позволяет снизить нагрузку на ЦП до < 1%. Однако, если условие «определенные действия» выполнено, цикл ломается ( по ложному условия повторения) и программа оживает.